# List of sanity test generators for C++?

Tags: c++

I have found only

http://ispras.linux-foundation.org/index.php/API_Sanity_Autotest

because it is listed on Wikipedia. Is there any other Sanity suite for C++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems API Sanity Autotest is the only one existent

Answer (score 1):

Valgrind ([http://valgrind.org/](http://valgrind.org)) can help you finding bugs with a memory error detector, two thread error detectors, a cache and branch-prediction profiler, a call-graph generating cache and branch-prediction profiler, and a heap profiler

Comment: It doesn't count as a sanity test generator.